# What's the state of the art in determining user location via IP address?

Tags: api, geolocation, location

I found myself trying to convert IP addresses into locations today, and found a number of options. They vary in methodology (some are downloadable databases, some are services, etc) and quality.

- Whois
- hostip.info
- ip2location.com
- maxmind
- Dayana
- geoiptool.com

There are more.

I know the quality of any of these tools can only be so high (users can proxy, etc), but I would like to know which of the above tools is generally the best, or if I should be using multiple services, or what. Does anyone have any experience actually comparing these to each other, or know where I can find such a comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using maxmind in an Asp.net site and it have been always reliable and quite fast to respond. Consider also using [Html5 geolocation](http://html5demos.com/geo) if you'll be dealing with browsers.